# How can I print the randomly selected index value?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm not able to print the value which I have randomly selected from drop-down e.g If I have selected index 4 and the value of index 4 is "ABC" then it is printing 4 not as ABC. Can you please help me to get a solution for this problem?

I have tried converting the index into a string but it doesn't worked

```
public class SC {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Dell\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32 (2)\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("http://website name");
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;


FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("C:\\Excel_data\\Testdata.xlsx");
               Workbook wb=WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
    Sheet sh=wb.getSheet("Sheet1");

        for(int i=0; i<=3; i++) 
            {
            Actions act = new Actions(driver);

        act.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='navbar-main']/div/div[2]/ul/li[3]/a"))).perform();
                driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1,TimeUnit.MINUTES);
                            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"navbar-main\"]/div/div[2]/ul/li[3]/ul/li[3]/div/ul/li[2]/a")).click();       //*[@id="navbar-main"]/div/div[2]/ul/li[3]/ul/li[3]/div/ul/li[2]/a

WebElement list = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"categoryDropDown\"]"));
        Random random = new Random();
        int index = random.nextInt(4)+1;
        Select listfin = new Select(list);
        listfin.selectByIndex(index);
        Thread.sleep(2000); 

WebElement itemsInDropdown1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"policyTermDropDown\"]"));
           Random random1 = new Random();
           int index1 = random.nextInt(4)+1;
           Select list1 = new Select(itemsInDropdown1);
           list1.selectByIndex(index1);
           Thread.sleep(2000);

        js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,-500)"); 
        Thread.sleep(1500);
        String a= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'totalCount\']")).getText();
            System.out.println(a +" "+"Scheme Found");


    sh.getRow(0).createCell(i).setCellValue(a + " "+"Scheme found");

FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("C:\\Excel_data\\Testdata.xlsx");
                        wb.write(fos);
                fos.close();
                }
            driver.close();

                }
            }
```

Comment: Can you pls elaborate what exactly you are trying to do with list &  itemsInDropdown1  variables, Are there two drop downs, which drop down value are you trying to print? what value are you trying to store in variable "a"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As provided in question, only print statement is

```
String a= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'totalCount\']")).getText();
        System.out.println(a +" "+"Scheme Found");
```

So text available at `id=totalCount` will be printed.

If you want to print selected option in dropdown then

```
 WebElement option = list1.getFirstSelectedOption();
    System.out.println(option.getAttribute("value"));
```

which will print selected option for list1 dropdown

Comment: @NeetiPatil good know, please accept it as answer so others know it.

Comment: Sure just did that